# Does Wireless Transmission imply flying or Travelling Particles in the air or in vacuum?

Tags: electromagnetism

1. Is it true that electromagnetic wave comprises of electric field and magnetic field both travels in the air or in vacuum to reach the receiver antenna?
2. If electromagnetic wave comprising electric and magnetic fields both synchronously and literally travels in a vacuum then , would it mean that the stream of particles in the conductor moves away to reach the receiver antenna ?
3. Can the electric field go beyond the conductor several miles away and come along with magnetic field, as in literally?

4.Which is true? The literal flying or travelling particles from the transmitter in the form of electric field reaches to the receiver antenna or because of the presence of magnetic field from transmitter thus it induces voltage in the receiver antenna?

Comment: You have at least 6 questions here, which makes this question *too broad*. We much prefer one question per post (but often are willing to stretch it to two or three questions that are closely related (such that answering one will likely answer the others as well)).

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes that is true
2. Assuming that you mean that the transmitting antenna transmits EM-Radiation, where the radiation is photons, which is then received by a receiving antenna, then yes. Just note that photons do not travel away from the reciever when they are being picked up.
3. An electric field is the region of space where an electric charge will have a force exerted upon it by said electric field. Also, yes an electric field can extend outside of a conductor. That's why your hair stands on it's end when near a charged balloon. Your hair is inside of the electric field put out by the charged balloon.
4. If a wire is magnetized, the Magnetic Field lines are in concentric circles around the wire. If a wire has an electric charge, the field lines radiate away from the wire like spokes on a wheel. Also note that magnetic fields and electric fields are not interchangeable. An electric charge is from charged particles like Protons or Electrons. A magnetic field is from the movement of charged particles. That's why you can have a charged balloon [From an abundance of electrons sitting "motionless" on the balloon, but need a wire and an electric current to have a magnetic field.

5.When a transmitter produces a signal, it's because you have a changing magnetic field. That is to say that the magnetic field is getting stronger and weaker. This change induces an electric current in the receiver. This is called Lenz' Law.

Comment: So you mean to say the varying stream of electrons or photons or wavicles etc. in the transmitting antenna  (i.e complex analog signal) are literally flying or traveling in air or vacuum and then get inside the receiving antenna to form back the transmitted information?

Comment: So, every particle is actually just a weird wave. This is called particle wave duality. If you imagine an electron field[similar to a magnetic field or electric field], a single electron is an excited region of that field. They need nothing to travel on. That excitation in the electron field, also called a quantum, excites the photon field to transmit an excited region of the photon field that is a photon. All electromagnetic radiation is nothing more than a bunch of particles of photons[remembering that a photon is nothing more than an excited field] that act as a wave.

Comment: That group of photons that are transmitted by the moving electrons radiate away in the form of electromagnetic radiation. Because they are just excited regions of a field that is in all of the universe, they need nothing to travel on. The group of photons acting as an electromagnetic wave will hit the antenna, then the electromagnetic wave will cause the electrons in the receiver to move[electrons move in the opposite way the photons do in order to create a magnetic field the opposing the magnetic field they received], and moving  electrons make an electric current that the radio can decipher.

Comment: So, you mean that electromagnetic wave (comprising electric and magnetic fields which are graphically presented in sinusoidal form) represents the variation of the amount of photons (not really traveling?) that repeat periodically for each wavelength beginning from the transmitting antenna up to receiving antenna?

Comment: Could it be correct to understand that each photon generates the electric and magnetic field like a moving single electron?